# Why do I get a 404 for googleapis.com/v1/projects chat-bison@001:predict?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform

I'm using the example curl I get from:

https://console.cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative/language/my-prompts/create/text?authuser=2&project=my-app

[image: curl]

https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-app/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/chat-bison@001:predict

but I get a 404 everytime. I have the right Bearer auth token. Everything seems to be correct but 404!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built URL apparently is incorrect.

1. The model is supposed to be `text-bison` (without the `@001`)
2. The URL "template" is supposed to be `https://${API_ENDPOINT}/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/${MODEL_ID}:predict` (`/models` was missing)

All in all:

```
API_ENDPOINT="us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com"
PROJECT_ID="<projectID>"
MODEL_ID="text-bison"

curl \
-X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
"https://${API_ENDPOINT}/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/${MODEL_ID}:predict" -d \
$'{
  "instances": [
    {
      "content": "Write a short poem:"
    }
  ],
  "parameters": {
    "temperature": 0.2,
    "maxOutputTokens": 256,
    "topP": 0.8,
    "topK": 40
  }
}'
```

Source: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/start/quickstarts/api-quickstart

Comment: This is a summarization and classification model, not the chat model. Is there any clarifications on how to call chat model via REST API?

Comment: @huksley just use the model `chat-bison` as in:
`"https://${endPoint}/v1/projects/${projectId}/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/chat-bison:predict"`

Comment: `text-bison@001` should also work. Note that the `chat-bison` models have different instance and prediction format.